# I am getting a "ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5" when trying to use Redis rq

Tags: python, redis, pickle, rq

I am trying to get Redis and rq working.

This is my main code:

from rq import Queue
from redis import Redis
from util import count_words_at_url
from rq.registry import FailedJobRegistry, Job
import time

if **name** == '**main**':

```
print('Hi')


# Tell RQ what Redis connection to use
redis_conn = Redis()
q = Queue(connection=redis_conn)  # no args implies the default queue

# Delay execution of count_words_at_url('http://nvie.com')
job = q.enqueue(count_words_at_url, 'http://nvie.com')
registry = FailedJobRegistry(queue=q)

# Show all failed job IDs and the exceptions they caused during runtime
for job_id in registry.get_job_ids():
    job = Job.fetch(job_id, connection=redis_conn)
    print(job_id, job.exc_info)

print(job.result)

# Now, wait a while, until the worker is finished
time.sleep(20)
print(job.result)
```

My background task is:

import requests

def count_words_at_url(url):
resp = requests.get(url)
return len(resp.text.split())

I get this output in the console:

```
Hi
a6d5bb76-7bc9-46e4-b6ba-c1f3e3305da8 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
984f6808-0b79-4d64-9bab-a6615ae88eaa Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
02b3ab72-90a9-4366-a160-14cedc9bad68 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
5978089c-d244-4049-b11d-0c3af85c1865 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
8484e4f5-9248-4022-b05b-b3342b1f7978 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
bdd57a11-f1df-4734-956d-254e81480d68 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
cf4eb163-bbd6-46f4-9d54-d34bb2ad9f51 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
ad168c8c-5757-4ef6-93e7-965494d7bf00 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
bcb07749-4839-40a7-ac46-760884cd37a7 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
043bfdb9-5b42-45ba-97c1-b1d8943797a6 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/johnvergo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5

and after 20 seconds, this:
None
```

Comment: You appear to be running Python 3.7. But your code is giving an error because it can't read a `pickle` file with protocol 5. Which is because protocol 5 was introduced in Python 3.8.

Comment: So I simply need to upgrade to Python 3.8?

Comment: I'm not saying that will 'simply' solve your problem. Some of the other libraries you are using may depend on 3.7. But installing 3.9 *side by side* with 3.7 will not give difficulties. I have 3.7–3.9 and 2.7 all installed. You could maybe find out if you can obtain the `pickle` file saved according to an earlier protocol. All versions of `pickle` can be asked to produce files according to earlier protocols, though there are limits. For example, I doubt if you can usefully save a Python 3 class in protocol 0 because Python 1.5.2 would not have understood it.